# Type error Python programming

Tags: python, compare, comparison

I am trying to write some code for an assignment in python. What I am not finding anywhere is what is wrong and why it will not run. It is sense and move robotic localization function. I do not understand why this line will not work.

```
q.append(p[i] * (hit * sensor_right + (1 - hit) * (1-sensor_right)))
```

- hit = a comparison between two strings. That evaluates to true or false which is 1 or 0, right?
- sensor_right = 0.7

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
File "vm_main.py", line 26, in <module> import main  
File "/tmp/sbdxfjuois/main.py", line 50, in <module> p = sense(p, measurements[k])
File "/tmp/sbdxfjuois/main.py", line 34, in sense q.append(p[i] * (hit * sensor_right + (1 - hit) * (1-sensor_right)))
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

Can you suggest anything for what I have here posted?

```
def sense(p, Z):
q = [ ]
for i in range(len(p)):
    hit = (Z == colors[i])
    q.append(p[i] * (hit * sensor_right + (1 - hit) * (1-sensor_right)))
s = sum(q)
for i in range(len(q)):
    q[i] = q[i]/s
return q
```

Comment: do some debugging, `print` the parts of that expression..

Comment: According to the error message, either `p[i]` or `sensor_right` are arrays.

Comment: It's simply saying that `p[i]` is a sequence (not a scalar!) and `(hit * sensor_right + (1 - hit) * (1-sensor_right))` is a `float`. It's not clear what you expect to happen, but standard Python does not define multiplication of sequences by floats.

Comment: okay, so yes p[i] is a 4x5 list of lists containing a uniform distribution of 0.05. I want to multiply each list position with which ever side of the expression (hit * sensor_right + (1 - hit) * (1-sensor_right) comes out non zero.

Comment: @ILikeTechnology: look into numpy; you can't multiply a list of lists by anything.

Answer (score 2):

As others have pointed out, this `p` variable is apparently a sequence of sequences.  You can verify this by putting

```
print(type(p))
print(type(p[i]))
```

before the append statement.  You'll probably see something like

```
tuple
tuple
```

If that's what you expected, then you'll need to loop over the other index of the array.  Also, does your `q` need to be returned with the same shape?  I suspect you want something more like this.

```
def sense(p, Z):
    q = p[:]
    for i in range(len(p)):
        for j in range(len(p[i])):
            hit = (Z == colors[i])
            q[i][j] = (p[i][j] * (hit * sensor_right + (1 - hit) * (1-sensor_right)))
    s = sum(q)
    for i in range(len(q)):
        q[i] = q[i]/s
    return q
```

Note that you also might want to look into numpy arrays.

Answer (score 0):

If you're correct about the other variables, it is telling you that `p[i]` is a sequence (most likely a list), which can't be multiplied by a float.  Perhaps `p[i]` is not what you're expecting it to be?

Try `print`ing `p[i]` before the line that throws an error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is what others have said.  You can only multiply a sequence by an int, not a float.
For example

```
>>> [1] * 3
[1, 1, 1]
>>> "f" * 6
ffffff
>>> [1] * 0.7
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

Double check your data type for p, to make sure it is supposed to be a sequence.  If that is truly what p should be, then make sure to convert the following to an int before multiplying

```
(hit * sensor_right + (1 - hit) * (1-sensor_right))
```

Comment: my p looks like this p = [[0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05],
     [0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05],
     [0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05],
     [0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05]]

Comment: just realized what I wrote and am laughing now a my previous statement about p.

Comment: clarification I am reading from p[i] the float 0.05 that it contains, multiplying that by the other expression and then writing it to q. They are both float? No?

Comment: @ILikeTechnology: If p is a list of lists, the `p[i]` is a list.  A list is not a float.

Comment: Do you know why it would work if p is a one dimensional list? It works when p = [0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2]. But when I start expanding p, still just trying to read what the list contains and multiply that number to put the result in a new list q, it falls apart. I know I am not understanding things correctly.

Comment: Yes, p[0] = [0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05]

Comment: Don't think of p as a 2-dimensional list.

Comment: Think of it as a list of lists. Each element is another list. p[i][j] would be a float for proper values of i and j.

Answer (score 0):

Related to what @Mike said, you could also do:

```
q = []
sum = 0
for i in p:
    sub_q = []
    for val in i:
        computed_val = val * (hit * sensor_right + (1 - hit) * (1-sensor_right))
        sum += computed_val
        sub_q.append(computed_val)
    q.append(sub_q)
```

I like that because it is more concise and doesn't have to build a bunch of ranges every time you call it, and it also reduces the number of times you iterate over the data, but to each their own.